# Postgresql Backup and restore using java with password

Tags: java, postgresql, backup, restore

I want to backup and restore a postgresql database using pg_dump.
The issue is : 
In command line when i execute this command :

```
pg_dump -h localhost -p 5432 -U postgres  -F t -f test2.tar  myDatabase
```

i get this prompet mesage to provide the database password:

```
 Mot de passe :
```

So, it works

But, in the context of java:
I can only do:

```
 String cmd = "pg_dump -U postgres -h localhost -p 5342";
                cmd += " -F t -f " + file.getCanonicalPath();
                cmd += " myDatabase";
                Process p = Runtime.getRuntime().exec(cmd);
                int result= p.waitFor();

if (result == 0) {
                    System.out.println("Backup created successfully");
                } else {
                    System.out.println("There is an error");
                }
```

The above code is not working. So, what i can do to provide the database password at runtime ?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

From PostgreSQL documentation about [pg_dump](http://www.postgresql.org/docs/9.5/static/app-pgdump.html):

> -w
>
> --no-password
>
> Never issue a password prompt. If the server requires password authentication and a password is not available by other means such as a .pgpass file, the connection attempt will fail. This option can be useful in batch jobs and scripts where no user is present to enter a password.

So can you try also passing the `-w` option on your `pg_dump`command and provide a `.pgpass` [file](http://www.postgresql.org/docs/9.3/static/libpq-pgpass.html) with the password?